# find content in cell then replace a content in other cell in same row

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I am trying to do as stated in the title.

I need to find NameB in

Example:

[image]

then replace "NOT YET" with "DONE"

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Dim myCell  As Range        
    For Each myCell In Columns("C").SpecialCells(2).Cells
        If myCell <> Range("C1") Then myCell = Range("C1")
    Next myCell    
End Sub
```

This is how it works:

- `SpecialCells(2).Cells` takes only the cells in column C, which are with values.
- Then it loops through them and changes these, which are not the same as C1.

As next steps:

- Make sure that for the next question in StackOverflow you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks for answering.. as for the suggestion, i've tried searching the other questin too

Answer (score 0):

`ReplaceContent` is the main sub that gets called which is why it's marked `Public`. The others are `Private` as they are only need to be called within the module.

```
Public Sub ReplaceContent()
    UpdateContent "NameB", 2
End Sub
```

`UpdateContent` is provided the name to look for `username`, as well as how many columns over you want your information to be populated into `updateColumnOffset`, and the completion message `completedMessage` which is set with a default value.

```
Private Sub UpdateContent(ByVal username As String, ByVal updateColumnOffset As Long, Optional ByVal completedMessage = "DONE")
    Dim users As Range
    Set users = GetCellsPopulatedWith(username)
    Dim user As Range
    For Each user In users
        If user.Value2 = username Then
            user.Offset(0, updateColumnOffset).Value2 = completedMessage
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`GetCellsPopulatedWith` is provided with the name to look up and searches for that name until it finds the first cell that was found and stops looking `Do While ... Loop` . The results get added together with `Union`

```
Private Function GetCellsPopulatedWith(ByVal username As String) As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = FindUserName(username, Sheet1.Range("A1"))

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        Set GetCellsPopulatedWith = foundCell

        Dim startAddress As String
        startAddress = foundCell.Address

        Dim previousCell As Range
        Set previousCell = foundCell
        Set foundCell = FindUserName(username, previousCell)
        Do While foundCell.Address <> startAddress
            Set GetCellsPopulatedWith = Union(GetCellsPopulatedWith, foundCell)
            Set previousCell = foundCell
            Set foundCell = FindUserName(username, previousCell)
            Debug.Print previousCell.Address, foundCell.Address
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

`FindUserName` is where the next cell with the name is found. Making a change here will keep results consistent.

```
Private Function FindUserName(ByVal username As String, ByVal previousCell As Range) As Range
    Set FindUserName = Sheet1.Columns("A").Find(What:=username, After:=previousCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Macros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA8Tc.png) this code may help you:

```
Dim value As String
Dim i As Integer
value = Range("A1").value
i = 1
Do While value <> ""

    If value = "NAMEB" Then
        Range("C" & i).value = "DONE"
    End If
    i = i + 1
    value = Range("A" & i).value
Loop
```

You can enhance it by turning it into a function and implementing parameters, for example:

```
Function SetResult(ByVal nameValue As String, ByVal resultValue As String)
    Dim value As String
    Dim i As Integer
    value = Range("A1").value
    i = 1
    Do While value <> ""
        If value = nameValue Then
            Range("C" & i).value = resultValue
        End If
        i = i + 1
        value = Range("A" & i).value
    Loop
    SetResult = "Done"
End Sub
```

And if you add a button to your spreadsheet you can use it this way:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim nameVal, resultVal, result As String

    nameVal = InputBox("Please insert the value you want to look for in Column A")
    resultVal = InputBox("Please insert the value you want to set in Column C")

    result = SetResult(nameVal, resultVal)

End Sub

Function SetResult(ByVal nameValue As String, ByVal resultValue As String) As String
     Dim value As String
     Dim i As Integer
     value = Range("A1").value
     i = 1
     Do While value <> ""

     If value = nameValue Then
         Range("C" & i).value = resultValue
     End If
     i = i + 1
     value = Range("A" & i).value
     Loop
     SetResult = "Done"
End Function
```

There are *many* ways to do what you need but this code, with some edition, can be reused in a variety of applications, not only Macros.

**Some screenshots**:
[image: Set search for NAMEC in Column A][image: Set value to "DONE BETTER" in Column C if criteria is matched in Column A][image: Value changed]

Comment: this helps me a lot.. i am not a pro developer, i'm just an ordinary college guy, so thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it does! Don't forget to [mark your question as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) after you are done and if any of the given answers suited you please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was best for you. Thanks!